# Rename columns in Data Extensions programmatically

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, soap, wsproxy

Is there a way to rename column names with WSProxy or another SSJS method in DEs? Columns have data in there so I cannot remove and add again.

EDIT:
I get this in error message when using WSProxy to delete/updateItem:

> WSProxy object is not valid in sendable content. This function is only
> allowed in non-sendable content

I guess we cannot use WSProxy

Comment: https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-use-wsproxy-to-work-with-data-extensions-in-ssjs/#update-de-fields. Have you tried this method?

Comment: Are you using wsproxy in a script activity? and not an email

Comment: WSProxy in script activity and the above mentioned url gave that error message. So i guess WSProxy cannot be used with sendable DEs

Comment: I was able to use the example WSProxy scripts Ivan has on his blog no problem. Perhaps if you share the code snippet you created, we can see where you went wrong?

Comment: Hello @Gortonington have you tried that on sendable DE that is part of attribute group?

Comment: DEs that are part of an attribute group are usually afforded a level of protection beyond your average DE. This can have adverse affects on the ability for API and other such programmatic methods to interact with them. As to the error you received, that is not a symptom of this though to my knowledge. Usually it would return a success message in those cases and then nothing happens.

Comment: Hello @Gortonington I have changed the script and it works. also it works for any kind of data extension. I cannot recreate the error I had though.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed script did proper error handling and it works for any type of Data Extensions. I cannot recreate the error I did get the other time.